# Why is the $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$ not $\pm$?

Tags: trigonometry

Given an angle $\theta$, the formulas for $\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$ and $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$ are either positive or negative, which is why $\pm$ is used in their formulas.  So, if $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\cos(\theta/2)}$, and both the numerator and denominator are either positive or negative (and unless $\theta$ is defined, we must assume they can be both), shouldn't the formula for $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$ also be $\pm$?

Below are the equations I am referring to.

$$\sin \left( \frac{u}{2} \right) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(u)}{2}}$$

$$\cos \left( \frac{u}{2} \right) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(u)}{2}}$$
$$\tan \left( \frac{u}{2} \right)=\frac{1-\cos(u)}{\sin(u)}=\frac{\sin(u)}{1+\cos(u)}$$

Comment: $\tan x$ is always $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, at least if $\cos x\ne0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: that was my thought too, until I second-guessed that the OP might be looking at some other formula that is not shared in the question...

Comment: The question of why the tan formula doesn't involve $\pm$ is the wrong question. The right question is to ask why the sin and cos formulae do require $\pm$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, your first two equations involve square roots, and the third doesn't.
The first requires a $\pm$ as $\sin u/2$ may be positive or negative, but by convention square roots are positive.

But (using duplication formulas for sine and cosine)
$$\frac{1-\cos u}{\sin u}=\frac{1-(1-2\sin^2(u/2))}{2\sin(u/2)\cos(u/2)}
=\frac{2\sin^2(u/2)}{2\sin(u/2)\cos(u/2)}=\frac{\sin(u/2)}{\cos(u/2)}=\tan(u/2)$$
etc.

Comment: But it is not known whether sin(u/2) or cos(u/2) is positive or negative, so why is tan(u/2) not either sin(u/2)/cos(u/2) or -sin(u/2)/cos(u/2)?  Does the substitution of trig identities you wrote out confirm it is not +-?

Comment: "It is not known whether..." For a given, known $u$, we can compute $\sin(u/2)$ and $\cos(u/2)$, including the sign. Give me any value of $u$, I'll tell you whether $\sin(u/2)$ is positive or negative! The issue is that the formulas for $\sin(u/2)$ and $\cos(u/2)$ in terms of $\cos(u)$ will not tell you the signs. It's not that the signs are "unknowable", just that these particular formulae will not reveal them. If you compute $\sin(u/2)$ using its Taylor series, for example, you'll know exactly what the sign is!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are referring to the identity often stated as:

$$\tan(\theta/2) = \pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$$

In some instances, such as solutions to an equation, the $\pm$ sign indicates *both* are valid.

In the case of values of functions only up to one of the two signs are valid for a specific angle $\theta$. You need to investigate which.

The most similar "correct" version of this identity is:

$$\tan^2(\theta/2) = \dfrac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$$

There are other versions of the tangent half-angle identity which do not contain this ambiguity, such as

$$\tan(\theta/2) = \dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Depend on $u$- the sign of $\cos \left( \frac{u}{2} \right)$ matter

[image]